# How to find sum of a field by finding chronological order in another field in R?

Tags: r, short, chronological

I have an excel file with below columns

[image]

I want to add duration field for each member (A and B) date wise.

In here I want data like:

```
UserName   Date   Duration


A          22-07-2019 2

B          22-07-2019 1
```

I tried below code but results are not as desired.
The date field is sorted like text field (not chronological).
Ex: 01-01-2020 then 01-02-2020 instead 01-01-2020 then 02-01-2020

Comment: Do you want a solution in Excel or a solution in R?  Both should be trivial.  If R, please also post your input data using `dput()` rather than as an image: it's not as easy to convert and image to a data frame, so please help us to help you.

Comment: I want a soulutin in R. I'm reading this table from excel file

Comment: @Wimpel, Thanks. I'm able to get the sum by the solution given by you. But The dates are sorted like text not by date.

Comment: then you should convert them to data-format first... For example using `as.Date()` or one of the many many other possibilities to convert strings to dates/posix.